# Benefits of WHERE filtering before performing SQL UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

My target RDBMS is SQL Server 2012 - but I'm interested in a general response here.

Let's consider the following SQL Update clause:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Active = 0 WHERE EffectiveDate < GETDATE()
```

Assuming that there could be MANY entries in *MyTable* where Active is already set to "0" for past events, would there be any huge performance benefit to performing the update like this instead?

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Active = 0 WHERE EffectiveDate < GETDATE() AND Active = 1
```

Comment: Depends on how your indexes are made.

Comment: Crono - I highly suspected that may be the case. I'm guessing that a general "best practice" in a circumstance like this would be to use my second variation - correct?

Comment: Likely, yes. But if your table has millions of records and there's no index on Active field then you might start to feel a difference. I'd suggest you make sure Active field is indexed first, and THEN yes your second variant will be the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have less writes (possibly as you state most is already 0?) and less updates to the indexes if you have indexes on `Active`

Comment: I think you've touched on my main point here - does SQL server actually *perform* a write if the column already has the desired value? I wasn't certain if (in general) it was smart enough to perform these types of optimizations intrinsically.

Comment: It will write even if the value is the same, yes.

Comment: @Crono - It generally won't except if updating CI key or using snapshot isolation. See [The Impact of Non-Updating Updates](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx)

Comment: I stand corrected. :) Nice article, I'll make sure to read it more deeply later on. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinSmith, will the record still appear in inserted / deleted trigger tables? If so then there could be performance concerns at this level.

Comment: @Crono - Yes. If the table has an `UPDATE trigger` then the logically updated rows still need to be copied to those even if not changed. The second statement in the question is definitely the best one to use.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks, that's what I first tought but your previous intervention put a doubt in my mind. :)

Comment: @astander - if you'll update your answer to include the article you linked in the comments, I will accept it as the final answer. I think this best represents the response I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the largest savings is in writing to the log.  Every row being updated generates log records.  By updating fewer rows, you will be logging fewer changes.

As noted not too long ago in another question, avoiding these updates can simplify some arcane aspects on triggers.  The"update(column)" syntax would identify that column as being modified, even though the value didn't change.

Comment: Don't mean to nag but the update function in the trigger would return the same thing regardless of the WHERE clause. :) Still, +1 for the log size.

Comment: Triggers are per statement, not per row. `update(column)` simply returns `true` if the `column` is assigned to at all.

Answer (score 1):

To add one more point to the other answers: In case you have an update trigger, there would be a difference, as it will only fired for the rows that fulfill the `WHERE` condition. Depending on the trigger content, this may cause undesired effects or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it will be!**

As you said there are many entries with `Active = 0` so limiting update query to only records that don't have active = 0 will mean to have less queries.